# Any pictures showing difference in moon between southern and northern observers?

Tags: the-moon

Since observers in different parts of Earth will be observing the moon at slightly different angles relative to its (choose reference vector: north pole, origin of latitude longitude position, whatever), they will be observing very slightly different faces of the moon.

I tried looking online to see if anyone had examples of photos of the moon taken from different parts of Earth at the same time but got overwhelmed of photos showing that the moon appears "upside down" in the southern hemisphere relative to what a northern observer would expect and couldn't find any.

Does anyone have or know where to find an example of what I'm asking?  Please note that I am *not* asking about the "upside down" moon effect I just described, and neither am I asking about lunar libration: I am specifically asking about being able to observe slightly different faces of the moon simply by standing somewhere else on Earth as someone else at the same time.

Comment: It's a tiny difference. Earth and Moon are much, MUCH further away that what most people imagine. Assuming two observers at the North and South pole, respectively, which is the absolute extreme case, the angular difference in how they see the Moon is less than 2 degrees of arc.

Comment: @FlorinAndrei, tiny indeed, but I'm still interested.

Comment: @Joshua re-reading your question I see you made that clearer than I first realized. I've deleted my comments. It's a great question!

Comment: A little searching found images of the Moon from Australia.

Comment: This is a bit of a cheat but if you use Virtual Moon Atlas (free download) you can change your viewing location and see the difference it makes.

Comment: @badjohn, yes, but I am looking for pictures taken *at the same time* from two different locations.  Due to lunar libration, pictures taken at different times as different locations are not guaranteed to look the same as pictures taken at the same time from different locations.

Comment: @Joshua Okay, so you are just interested in the orientation.  In that case, Florin's comment is plausible.  Some simple trigonometry could answer the question for you.

Comment: @badjohn, my question is whether any such pictures exist, not what the expected angle difference is.

Comment: I tried looking for stereo images but the cameras would have to be 100,00 km apart to perceive a stereo effect. I learned that stereo images were [made in the mid 1800s](http://physics.kenyon.edu/EarlyApparatus/Astronomy/Moon_Stereo/Moon_Stereo.html) using images from different times in the libration cycles.

Comment: Observers at the equator and at the pole each have different zenith orientation and therefore a different visible hemisphere of the universe.. At the equator the moon would appear along a higher lunar arc. At the pole the lunar arc would appear closer to the horizon.

Comment: @JohnCanon, I'm asking about how the moon itself would appear different, not about how where it appears in the sky would be different.

Comment: different but somewhat related question [Different full moon face on different places on Earth same time](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/27125/7982)